# IntelliJ Java inspection non primitive Boolean in 'if' statements

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I would like to be warned in my Java code where an 'if' statement is based on a non-primitive Boolean condition.

For example:

```
void anyMethod() {
   if(getCondition()) {
   ...
   }
}

Boolean getCondition() {
...
}
```

where `getCondition()` may return TRUE, FALSE or null

That kind of 'if' control may produce NullPointerException and should be avoided.

In IntelliJ, I tried to create a custom inspection pattern but mine doesn't work.
If I explicitely put a @Nullable annotation on getCondition() then the default inspections work, but this solution still relies on a manual task that may not be done rigorously (putting @Nullable everywhere a method return a Boolean) and does not cover codes where the condition is a local Boolean variable.

How can I write an IntelliJ inspection pattern to track this case?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What's the reason for getCondition to return a boxed boolean in the first place?

Comment: getCondition() may return null when the data it needs is not available. It may occurs when it is part of a class which have optional attributes.

Comment: I think it's a bad design. If data doesn't exist, the condition should probably default (either true or false, that's you knowing best). Or if something should really be there and is not, then an exception should be thrown. But I wouldn't rely on a boxed boolean, what do you expect the caller of the function to do when null is found is what you should do on function side in the first place.

Comment: If "optional attributes" is the use case here, I would rather have an `Optional<Boolean>` than a `Boolean` possibly being `null`.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I know that the code could be better (what @MC Emperor proposes is probably the right way), but my point here is not to challenge the possibility of writing a method that returns a Boolean, but to find a way to track where the 'bad' practice of using Boolean in 'if' statements occurs in existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom inspection for this like so:

First go to the inspections tab in the IntelliJ settings page. Then click on the plus button and then "Add Search Template"

[image]

Then use the pattern:

```
if ($expression$) {$statement$;}
```

Add the filter "type=java.lang.Boolean" to the `$expression$` template and "count=[0,inf]" to the `$statement$` template. Remember to put the cursor over the template when adding filters.

The end result should look like this:

[image]

Give the inspection a name, a tooltip, a description, and a suppress ID, and you're done.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sweeper, you just answered exactly what I expected! It works like a charm, and will help me track more code's flaws ;-)